# Adding Scatter Chart Data Label If XValue > Value

Tags: excel, vba, charts, label, scatter

I have a scatter plot with 100+ series and I'd like to add some data labels to those series where the horizontal value is greater than the vertical value - i.e. where XValue>Value.

I use the following code to add data labels to all series:

```
Dim mySeries As Series
Dim seriesCol As SeriesCollection
Dim i As Integer

Set seriesCol = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection

For Each mySeries In seriesCol
    Set mySeries = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(j)
    With mySeries
            .ApplyDataLabels
            .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
            .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
            .DataLabels.Font.Size = 6
    End With
    j = j + 1
Next
```

I would assume I'd add an 'If' command prior to the 'With' command, along the following lines:

```
If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(j).XValues > _
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Values  Then
```

However this condition doesn't seem to work. I'd be grateful if you could point out where I've gone wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: You need to go one step further and iterate through the `Values` and `XValues` one by one.  That is, you cannot ask Excel to compare two arrays/ranges with a single operator: `XValues > Values` will not work.  See very similar question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/920162/hide-data-label-containing-series-name-if-value-is-zero/920246#920246.  If you cannot get an answer from that question, update your code and I'll post an answer below.  If you get your own answer, add it below!

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look at that and think I understand it. However surely working through the XValues and Values separately wouldn't result in what I am trying to achieve? If I set a number (e.g. XValues > 10 and Values > 10) then this wouldn't apply a label to any instance where XValue would be 20 but Value would be 5 (i.e. where XValues > Values). Would I not need to compare both directly?

Comment: Yes, compare them directly, but ultimately you will have a statement like `XValues(i) > Values(i)` where you are going through the arrays "one-by-one".  I just meant to say that you will have to iterate the arrays instead of trying to compare them as objects.  Hopefully that's less confusing. :)